# ansible/terraform-provider-ansible - > specifies unknown plugin 'cloud.terraform.terraform_provider

Tags: ansible, terraform

As described in the blog post https://www.sysadminstories.com/2023/04/a-quick-look-at-terraform-provider-for.html, I have created the same Terraform deployment, but with a difference in the Azure cloud. I have created a Linux VM and then executed the following code:

```
resource "ansible_host" "azu_instance" {
  name = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.mylinuxvm.public_ip_address
  variables = {
    ansible_user                 = var.ansible_user
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file = var.ansible_ssh_key
  }
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_20_seconds]
}
```

In the Azure portal, I am not getting a DNS name for the Linux VM, only an IP address, which I pass to the Ansible inventory file. I hope this is okay.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error:

```
WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /inventory.yml with auto plugin: inventory config 'ansible_terraform_provider/v2/inventory.yml' specifies unknown plugin 'cloud.terraform.terraform_provider' [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse ansible_terraform_provider/v2/inventory.yml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse ansible_terraform_provider/v2/inventory.yml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port. [WARNING]: Unable to parse ansible_terraform_provider/v2/inventory.yml as an inventory source [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
```

I have already registered the Terraform provider:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
erraform.io/builtin/terraform is built into Terraform

Reusing the previous version of azure/azapi from the dependency lock file

Reusing the previous version of ansible/ansible from the dependency lock file

Reusing the previous version of hashicorp/azurerm from the dependency lock file

Reusing the previous version of hashicorp/random from the dependency lock file

Reusing the previous version of hashicorp/time from the dependency lock file

Using the previously installed ansible/ansible v1.0.0

Using the previously installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.72.0

Using the previously installed hashicorp/random v3.5.1

Using the previously installed hashicorp/time v0.9.1

Using the previously installed azure/azapi v1.9.0
```

Thank you for any tips or a link to the solution for this issue.

Comment: It looks like you did not [install the relevant collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cloud.terraform#installing-this-collection)

Comment: @Zeitounator 
Thank you very much for the tip and your help. 

After I installed that, I can move on.
ansible-galaxy collection install cloud.terraform

I wish you a nice week
Dim